# Permalink error 404 with number as product name

Tags: woocommerce, numbers, http-status-code-404, permalinks

I got products whom name is a number serial (i.e 1670).
I use base shop in permalink setting. When I am accessing URL with product name as number, I got error 404.

If I edit the permalink from 
to , it works.

I notice A bug when using product number as product name, even I installed it on newly wordpress installation.

I am amaze to see that no one is noticed major bug in woocommerce yet.

Comment: Product titles using that same numbers ?

Comment: Not really a "bug" as you say - it is designed to work that way for categories. [There is a solution here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38483252/woocommerce-only-numbers-in-product-name-issue)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WooCommerce: only numbers in product name - issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38483252/woocommerce-only-numbers-in-product-name-issue)